# TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not list

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote a really simple python sever program using the sockets. But i am getting the above mentioned error. I dont know what I made wrong. The code is

```
import socket
ms=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ainfo=socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1',1234)
ms.bind(ainfo)
ms.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr=ms.accept()
    data=ms.recv()
    if not data:
        break;
    ms.sendall(data)
conn.close()
ms.close()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 4, in <module>
    ms.bind(ainfo)
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in `ainfo[0][4]` instead of ainfo. Because ainfo is a list of tuples. socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1',1234) returns

```
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 1234)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>, 17, '', ('127.0.0.1', 1234)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>, 0, '', ('127.0.0.1', 1234))]
```

So you need to use the index ainfo[0][4], to access the ip and port.

Alternately, you could just use `ms.bind(('127.0.0.1',1234))` directly.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the call to `socket.getaddrinfo()`. Try this instead:

```
ms.bind(('127.0.0.1',1234))
```

Quoting the [`socket` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> Socket addresses are represented as follows: ... A pair `(host, port)` is used for the AF_INET address family, where `host` is a string representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like `'daring.cwi.nl'` or an IPv4 address like `'100.50.200.5'`, and `port` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I used ms.bind(ainfo[0][4]) to get the correct answer.